# How to query in sql with duplicate records?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i have ITEAM A and ITEAM B table. For example

```
 Table 1)     ITEAM A

ID   DATA
1    J
2    C
3    P
```

Table 2)     ITEAM B

```
ID   DATA
1    C
2    P
3    J
4    R

Expected Result

Result:
C
C
J
J
P
P
R
```

How to fetch records combined ITEAM A and ITEAM B with ascending order and duplicate records in sql? please help someone

Comment: Take a look at the JOIN syntax  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html  (Specifically, you'll probably just want a CROSS JOIN, if your requirement is as simple as you state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT data FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT data FROM tableB
ORDER BY data
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `DATA` FROM ITEAMA UNION ALL
SELECT `DATA` FROM ITEAMB ORDER BY `DATA`
```

Comment: In this query you select twice from the same table `ITEAM` giving different aliases `A` and `B` to this table in the subqueries. I doubt that OP needs in this..

Comment: `DATA` keyword is reserved because it is a part of `LOAD DATA`. In this case it does not need in quoting.